# How to configure Postgis for GeoDjango on Openshift

Tags: django, openshift, postgis, geodjango

After creating a new application in Openshift with django and postgres9.2 cartridges, I'm stuck on how to setup geodjango.

I tried running

```
psql -d db_name -f /usr/share/pgsql/contrib/postgis-64.sql
psql -d db_name -f /usr/share/pgsql/contrib/spatial_ref_sys.sql
```

But its throwing up error like

```
psql:/usr/share/pgsql/contrib/postgis-64.sql:7774: ERROR:  type "box2d" does not exist
psql:/usr/share/pgsql/contrib/postgis-64.sql:7775: ERROR:  type "geometry" does not exist
```

what do you think I should do ?

Comment: Why not just [`CREATE EXTENSION postgis;`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/gis/install/postgis/#creating-a-spatial-database-with-postgis-2-0-and-postgresql-9-1)?

Comment: Thank's @MikeT that worked. I couldn't find any documentation for that anywhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following [these instructions](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/gis/install/postgis/#creating-a-spatial-database-with-postgis-2-0-and-postgresql-9-1), the recommended way to install PostGIS 2.0+ on PostgreSQL 9.1+ is to:

```
CREATE EXTENSION postgis;
```